# Кривая работа GetExtendedTcpTable

Tags: delphi, tcp, windows-11

Используя код из ответа в этой теме: https://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=122488
**GetExtendedTcpTable** криво работает, **dwNumEntries** содержит правильное количество соединений, но сама таблица содержит всегда одну запись.
Есть идеи почему?

---

Delphi 11 (28.0.42600.6491)
Windows 11 (10.0.22000)

Comment: На основании чего сделан вывод об одной записи? Да, в структуре задекларирован массив размерностью [0..0], т.е. один элемент. Но это "штатная" сишная фишка, не мешающая обращению к последующим индексам. Т.е. задекларирован только один элемент, а все остальные сидят "в тени", далее в этом массиве. Собственно, код ответа по указанной ссылке действует именно так.

Comment: @kami "Range check error" + debug показывает одну запись

Comment: Да, range check error действительно тут можно словить (компилятор искренне считает, что элемент один), ну а дебаг может показать только то, что явно описано в структурах, те самые "теневые" элементы он не увидит. Поставьте до метода, перебирающего элементы, директиву {$R-}, а после {$R+}. В дополнение хочу заметить, что в релизной конфигурации по умолчанию стоит R-, а R+ несколько замедляет код.

Comment: @kami Действительно заработало! спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо **kami** за ответ в комментариях.

Перед переборкой таблицы надо ставить **{$R-}** а после **{$R+}**
Тобишь надо отключать проверку границы массива.